# Returning A Value From AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I want to build a function that creates an AlertDialog and returns the string that the user entered, this the function I have for creating the dialog, how do I return the value?

```
String m_Text = "";
private String openDialog(String title) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
    builder.setTitle(title);

    final EditText input = new EditText(view.getContext());
    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL);
    builder.setView(input);

    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            m_Text = input.getText().toString();
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    builder.show();

// return string
}
```

Comment: `return m_text`? You're assigning the value in the OK handler... Does that not work?

Comment: I want the function to return m_text

Comment: Ah, `builder.show` is not a blocking function. You'll either need to block your method until the value is ready or use a callback mechanism.

Comment: If the String m_text is defined globally why do you need it to return? Once the method is through and the user enters ok the value will be stored. just make it type void

Comment: No, you can not. If you do that, it will block your UI thread. you should try to make it asynchronous (as using listener, callback...).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The call `builder.show()` which opens your `AlertDialog` is not a blocking call. In other words, the subsequent instructions will be executed without waiting for the `AlertDialog` to finish (return). You should interact with it by using some *callback*. For instance, your `OnClickListeners` are an implementation of such a pattern.

### A simple callback pattern

One clean way to achieve what you want is to create a *Functional Interface* which is an interface having only one method. You would use it for handling your callbacks.

## Example

```
interface OnOK{
    void onTextEntered(String text);
}
```

And then you would alter your method to be like:

```
private void openDialog(String title, final OnOK onOK) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
    builder.setTitle(title);

    final EditText input = new EditText(view.getContext());
    input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_NORMAL);
    builder.setView(input);

    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
          //Oi, look at this line!
          onOK.onTextEntered(input.getText().toString());
       }
    });

    builder.show();
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
openDialog("Title", new OnOK() {
   @Override
   onTextEntered(String text) {
      Log.i("LOG", text);
   } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me like you have stored the value of the inputted text in the m_Text field. You can either just return that field or have a variable within the function in which you store the value to be returned.

Where you have:

```
//Return string
```

simply replacing with:

```
return m_Text;
```

should do the job.

Comment: No that wouldn't work, it will return an empty string because the return happens before the user click OK.

Comment: In which case what you're asking is slightly different. You won't be able to return in your openDialog method, since as you say it's just the opening of the dialog.

Unless you're running this on a worker thread and can sleep until a return value is sent.

Answer (score -1):

Create another method in the same class that accepts a string value, then call that function providing the value of `input.getText().toString()` from your `setPositiveButton` onclick event

Comment: This sounds like a callback pattern - worth clarifying that so OP can easily lookup other examples.